# run gcloud with .sh file on jenkins shows gcloud: command not found

Tags: jenkins

Running gcloud command with .sh file on mac is fine, but not on jenkins.
see pic below:

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the `gcloud` executable path correctly?

Comment: what is that? Can you give me more details? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up trying many ways, I find there is an Environment path column on Jenkins System Configuration page. Putting the google-cloud-sdk/bin path into the column will solve the problem.